# How to format the time in this Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I want to format a Google Sheet cell when I read it in my script but it comes out 25 minutes later.
The cell's time is 20:00:00 but the output is "20:25". I am using this

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dataRow[9], "GMT+2", HH:mm");
```

Without using it the time comes as "1899-12-30T18:25:08.000Z" even though the cell's content is 20:00:00. Any ideas how to remove the extra 25 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Spreadsheet's time zone settings.

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dataRow[9], SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm");
```

Comment: The output is "TypeError: Can't call method "getSpreadsheetTimeZone" of null."

Comment: @Vais That's because there is no active spreadsheet. How are you getting the spreadsheet in the original code?

Comment: `function doGet(e){
 var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").getSheets()[5];
return selectedsheet(sheet); 
}`

Comment: @Vais You need to get the spreadsheet from the sheet using [`getParent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getparent). So `sheet.getParent().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`.

Comment: Thank you very much you saved me so much time!